# My model is predicting an array of numbers rather than defined labesl

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am new to neural networks and I have trained my multi-label cnn model. Now I want to make some predictions on new images. I want to get labels predicted after using `model.predict(image)`, however it generates an array of just numbers like below.

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 294ms/step
array([[1.2423882e-07, 4.8644133e-10, 6.2801077e-11, ..., 5.9059038e-09,
    7.9583238e-08, 1.8839316e-07],
   [6.7338499e-07, 3.7959146e-11, 6.3526181e-12, ..., 6.6384481e-10,
    6.5803110e-09, 7.2412973e-09],
   [3.4079651e-06, 1.3292389e-12, 1.1482074e-09, ..., 2.3795290e-09,
    4.0437489e-09, 2.5665909e-09],
   ...,
   [4.5694168e-09, 5.8126518e-14, 7.4569753e-18, ..., 9.1445762e-16,
    8.6637960e-15, 1.7640524e-11],
   [7.3903612e-09, 1.1566522e-13, 6.5436875e-17, ..., 7.0952320e-15,
    8.3692771e-14, 1.2283501e-10],
   [7.1919551e-08, 1.9803466e-14, 2.5265929e-16, ..., 5.3995962e-13,
    5.4146050e-12, 3.9835553e-09]], dtype=float32)
```

I have tried this code below.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform

def load(filename):
  np_image = Image.open(filename)
  np_image = np.array(np_image).astype('float32')/255
  np_image = transform.resize(np_image, (256, 256, 3))
  np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image, axis=0)
  return np_image

image = load('/content/1000_IM-0003-1001.dcm.png')
loaded_2.predict(image)
```

I want to show labels instead of an array of numbers.

### Model Architecture

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 196, 196, 16)      1216      
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_4 (Batc  (None, 196, 196, 16)     64        
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling  (None, 98, 98, 16)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 dropout_6 (Dropout)         (None, 98, 98, 16)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_5 (Conv2D)           (None, 94, 94, 32)        12832     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling  (None, 47, 47, 32)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_5 (Batc  (None, 47, 47, 32)       128       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 dropout_7 (Dropout)         (None, 47, 47, 32)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_6 (Conv2D)           (None, 43, 43, 64)        51264     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling  (None, 21, 21, 64)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_6 (Batc  (None, 21, 21, 64)       256       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 dropout_8 (Dropout)         (None, 21, 21, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)           (None, 17, 17, 64)        102464    
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPooling  (None, 8, 8, 64)         0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_7 (Batc  (None, 8, 8, 64)         256       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 dropout_9 (Dropout)         (None, 8, 8, 64)          0         
                                                                 
 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 4096)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 128)               524416    
                                                                 
 dropout_10 (Dropout)        (None, 128)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256      
                                                                 
 dropout_11 (Dropout)        (None, 64)                0         
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 524)               34060     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 735,212
Trainable params: 734,860
Non-trainable params: 352
```

### Labels

Labls are one hot encode like below

```
y.shape
(4312, 524)
```

Comment: In order to help you we need to know what's your model's architecture, especially the output layer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have a [softmax](https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/#:%7E:text=%5Bsource%5D-,softmax,-function) as activation function in the last dense layer. So you are seeing the output probability distribution that gives the probability for each of the 524 classes. Just use :

```
tf.math.argmax(
    input,
    axis=None
)
```

input is your ouput tensor that you already have, and the axis equal to 1. As ouput you will have the index of the class with the greatest probability with the dimensions [batch, 1]